# Как вращать картинку в java

Tags: java, swing, rotate

Я писала код на java и мне понадобилась вращать объект вокруг своей оси, я догадываюсь, что это надо делать через метод rotate(), но не знаю как. Вот самая главная часть кода:

```
public void CreateOrganism() {
        OrganismX = (int) (Math.random() * 1400 + 101);
        OrganismY = (int) (Math.random() * 700 + 101);

        loadImage();
    }

    public void loadImage() {
        ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon("img/m0.png");
        var_organism = imageIcon.getImage();

    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(var_organism, OrganismX, OrganismY, this);
    }
```

Comment: Пожалуйста помогите

Comment: http://beginwithjava.blogspot.com/2009/02/rotating-image-with-java.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В начале нужно сделать приведение Graphics в Graphics2D:

```
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
```

И примерно так указать аргументы `rotate()` как привел пример ниже. Переменную `int degrees` я в классе заранее создал со значением `1`, но вы можете указывать то значение с какого угла вам нужно начать вращение.

```
g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(degrees), var_organism.getWidth(this)/2, var_organism.getHeight(this)/2);
```

Метод `drawImage()` добавляйте в код после `rotate()`.

И чтобы изображение вращалось запустите, где вам нужно будет, цикл с каждой итерацией изменяющий значение `degrees` и обновляющий графику.
Пример который я в метод поместил:

```
  public void animation() {

    for(int x = 0; x<1000; x++) {

      panel.repaint(); 
      this.degrees++;

      try {
        Thread.sleep(15);
     }catch(Exception ex) {}     
    }   
  }
```